# Image uploaded on dropbox does not have any content

Tags: file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox api uploadAsync to upload an image which in itself is passed in raw data form from another POST request. The upload is successful in terms that there is a file now on dropbox. But when I access that file, it says it has no contents. Why is it uploading file without content? Here is what I have tried

```
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 imageStream.Position = 0;
 memoryStream.Position = 0;
 imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
     var dropboxClient = new DropboxClient(token);
     var folder = "XYZ";
     var fileName = "ABC";
     var upload = dropboxClient.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + fileName, Dropbox.Api.Files.WriteMode.Add.Instance, autorename:true, body: memoryStream);
                upload.Wait();
            });
task.Wait();
```

imageStream is the Stream which I get from a POST request. It has raw image data.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The `CopyTo` may leave the `memoryStream` position at its end. Try seeking `memoryStream` back to its beginning before the upload.

Comment: @Greg. Thanks I will try this